# How to take time.Time as API body raw

Tags: api, go, controller, beego

> Problem is 2019/04/09 12:14:08.780 [C] [panic.go:522]  Handler crashed with error interface conversion: interface {} is string, not time.Time

```
// SingleTenantUsage
// @Param   startTime   time    true "startTime"
// @Param   endTime     time    true "endTime"
// @router /singleTenantUsage [post]
func (h *HypervisorController) SingleTenantUsage() {
   var bodyBytes []byte
   raw := make(map[string]interface{})
   if h.Ctx.Request.Body != nil {
     bodyBytes, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(h.Ctx.Request.Body)
   }

   json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &raw)

   usageSingle, err := compute.UsageSingleTenant(raw["tenantID"].(time.Time),raw["startTime"].(time.Time), raw["endTime"].(time.Time))   <---- error here

}
```

[image]

Comment: Change the order of the two last lines. And please do not ignore errors.

Comment: @mkopriva which line?

Comment: @mkopriva please check out my updated code

Comment: You should change the order of the two last lines, that is, call `json.Unmarshal` before you attempt to read the `raw` variable. Do not expect a map value to contain anything if you haven't put anything into it yet.

Comment: @mkopriva I'm so sorry, I just didn't copy correct. I just updated it.

Comment: Go does not support type casting/coercion, there's no builtin language feature that allows you to turn a `string` into `time.Time`. The expression `v.(T)` is a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). So you should type assert the timestamp values as `string` not as `time.Time` and then parse those strings using the `time` package.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you, sir. Can you give me a hint as Answer?, Let me accept your answer as a comment.

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/hu2OmmdIpyV